# Getting correct MIME Type using PHP

Tags: php

Where can I get the four magic files to be included in the `C:\xampp\php\extras` folder to get the correct MIME type(`$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE,'C:/xampp/php/extras')`)?

Comment: @AxelAmthor  I have been googling it  and I found this link  http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=23617&package_id=18878 but it is redirecting to someother page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finally i found an answer...The following is the code i have used.*

`list($width, $height, $image_type) = getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
 $mime_photo = image_type_to_mime_type($image_type);`

**Description**
 getimagesize() function can be used to get the width,height,image type etc.
Then i used  image_type_to_mime_type() function with parameter as $image_type.This function returns the correct MIME Type.

If you are using ($_FILES["photo"]["type"]== "image/jpeg") to compare the image type and suppose suppose you are changing the extension of a file say 'myprofile.txt' to 'myprofile.jpg' the comparison will be true,it read as 'image/jpeg',but if you are comparing using the MIME type then it will be false.

comparing using content type:

```
     if (($_FILES["photo"]["type"]== "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"]== "image/jpg"))
                {
                    echo 'The image is valid and its type is '.$_FILES["photo"]["type"];
                }
                else {
                   echo 'The image is invalid and its type is '.$_FILES["photo"]["type"];
                }
Comparing using MIME type:
if (($mime_photo== "image/jpeg") || ($mime_photo== "image/jpg"))
                {
                    echo 'The image is valid and its MIME Type is '.$mime_photo;
                }
                else {
                    echo 'The image uploaded is invalid and its MIME Type is '.$mime_photo;
                }
```